# テーブルの連結とグループ化のSQLの作成

Tags: sql

SQL初心者です。

下記のSQL練習サイトの13番に関する質問です。
テーブルの連結とグループ化のSQLの作成にだいぶ煮詰まっているので
アプローチの仕方について教えてください。
「下に示す様に、各試合ごとに各チームの得点を表示する。 この問題は、ここまでまだ未解説のSQL構文「CASE WHEN」を使用する。」
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation/ja

team1とteam2に対して、goalテーブルからスコアを集計(GROUP BY)してあげなければいけないところまでは分かっているんですが
gameテーブルとgoalテーブルをどう分割し、どうグループ化したら良いのかわかりません。。

ここまでは出来ています。

```
SELECT ga.mdate,ga.team1
  FROM game ga ,goal go1
    WHERE ga.id = go1.matchid
      AND ga.team1 = go1.teamid
    ORDER BY ga.mdate
```

### 追記

user20098さん

ご返答ありがとうございます。
可能であれば、勉強のために
解答例示していただけないでしょうか。

以下のように、全ての試合のチーム名とゴールしたチーム名を
出すところまでは出来たんですが…
`[CASE WHEN]`を使用してteam1とteam2の得点を集計するやり方が分からないです。
(提示していただいたポイントの一番下しかできていないです。)

```
SELECT ga.mdate,ga.team1 ,ga.team2,go.teamid as goalTeam
FROM game ga
LEFT OUTER JOIN goal go ON ga.id = go.matchid
ORDER BY ga.mdate , ga.id
```

Comment: RYUBO さん、回答として投稿されていたコメントを質問文に追記する形に変える編集をさせていただきました。回答欄は回答を投稿する場所ですので、今後も回答に何かあれば回答へのコメントか質問文への追記として行っていただくと幸いです :)

Comment: nekketsuuuさん 承知しました。コメントだと上手く改行が入らず見づらいので、今後は質問文への追記します。

Answer (score 1):

＃当該ページの趣旨としてよろしくないと思うので、正解ずばり回答するのは一旦避けます。ポイントだけ。

基本はページ記載の例を拡張すればよいと思います。ポイントは次の3点と考えます。

- SQL文に`team1`に対する`CASE WHEN`の記載があると思いますが、同じ感じで`team2`についても記載する
- SQL文(select文の結果)を一時テーブルとして、一時テーブルを`select`して一時テーブルの`score1`、`score2`で集計(`sum`)する
- 試合によっては両チーム得点なし(`goal`テーブルにレコードがない)場合があるので、`game`と`goal`を`INNER JOIN`するとそういう試合が出力されないので、2テーブルの結合を工夫する

参考: ページ記載のSQL。

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END score1
  FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id
```

参考になれば幸いです。

---

## 追記

正解と判定されるSQL文です。

```
SELECT mdate,team1,sum(score1) score1,team2,sum(score2) score2 FROM (
    SELECT mdate,
      team1,
      CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END score1,
      team2,
      CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END score2
      FROM game LEFT OUTER JOIN goal ON matchid = id
) t
group by mdate,team1,team2
order by mdate
```

＃他の手段もあると思いますが、SQLの例を問題文のヒントに沿って拡張するとこういうSQL文になると思います。